# Email sent via sendgrid is not being delivered

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have choose sendgrid to sent email to my mail accounts. I used the php curl to do so.

When i run the curl scrip sending the mail to sendgrid server

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
```

I got `{"message":"success"}` json response

But the message is not being delivered to my mail account (say google)

Comment: Have you tested to send your message to other mails providers? Have you checked in sendgrid interface the log for that message?

Comment: @Veve yes on the yahoo as well

Comment: Not a really tolerant webmail too... Have you checked the log in sendgrid interface?

Comment: ok i have the mail sent however the mail sent to my gmail account are all in the spam section and mail sent to yahoo are marked as deferred in the sendgrid dashboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your email was sent and delivered, but Gmail has marqued it as spam. There are a lot of ressources online and here to avoid to be classified as spam but it's a little bit too broad to be detailled here.
For your Yahoo test, [as explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/339662/what-does-mail-deferred-mean-in-linux-logwatch),

> "deferred mail" is simply mail that was unable to deliver to the
>   sender and has been added to the mail queue.